How to setup HTTPS connections with self-signed cert on SharePoint 2013
I got a problem when adding SSL to my SharePoint 2013 on-premises installation (Windows Server 2012).
The website works well with HTTP, and I followed some instructions as following:

Create self-signed SSL
Go to the SharePoint tree, binding the website with HTTPS and port 443. The certificate is the one just created.
In the Internet Explorer, go to SharePoint administration, choose Application Management then Alternate Access Mapping.

I add "s" to HTTP, Default to the Zone. But when browsing on the IE, I got error HTTP 404 for https://mydomain. If I go back to SharePoint administration and remove the "s" for this URL, all works fine. So, I failed to add SSL to my SharePoint URL.
I only used self-signed certificate. I tried to "copy to file" .crt and add it in Manage Computer Certificates->SharePoint but still no hope.
I succeeded in opening the SharePoint with HTTPS inside the Windows Server 2012 regardless of the warning of a "certificate error". However, I cannot open it from my PC; Chrome says "This site can't be reached".

Have you followed the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013? There is a lot to do in on-prem SharePoint servers to set up HTTPS connections correctly. Also, SP 2013 reached end of life 1 year ago, April 2023. Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 reached end of life in October 2023 as well. You really ought to upgrade (you'll have to go step-wise, 2013 -> 2016 -> 2019, rather than jump straight to 2019 or 2022), or switch to SharePoint Online.

In order to help, we would probably need to see more details about the certificates in your environment. Does your PC have a root certificate from the SharePoint server in order to trust certificates generated by that (or both server and PC can have a root cert from a trusted 3rd certificate authority if you're in an enterprise setting). What OS does your PC run? Windows 10? Or Windows 11?

Thank @TylerH for the responses. My PC run Windows 10 Pro. I used this SharePoint for test because of my client request. My certificate is created by going to IIS management, then choose Server Certificate and Create self-signed certifcate, Personal. I will try to send this certificate to my PC and put it in root certificate to see if it works.

Hi @TylerH I installed this certificate in  my PC (both in Trusted Root Certification Authorities and in Intermediate Certification Authorities) but still the website can't be reached.

You cannot rely on self-signed certs from IIS anymore unless you are using it for very old browsers (e.g. pre-2017 versions) due to the hashing algorithm used by IIS (SHA-1) being phased out in favor of SHA-256 or SHA-512, etc. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46641473/trust-a-self-signed-cert-from-iis for information. That is likely the root of your issue. tl;dr use MMC or PowerShell to generate a self-signed certificate, specifying the SHA-256 algorithm instead.

Thanks for the information. I will try this way.

And I confirmed that it works well with Firefox version 35

Which came out in 2015, before SHA-1 was deprecated... so that tracks :-)
